# Iam getting an error as couldn't recognize data in image file, i also tried with gif, jpeg, png extensions

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried this code with jpeg, gif, jpg, png and even with single slash but no output please help

```
from tkinter import *
import os
os.chdir("/storage/emulated/0/Fonts")
print(os.getcwd())
root=Tk()
c=Canvas(root,width=500,height=500)
c.pack()
myimage=PhotoImage(file='//storage//emulated//0//F  onts//Jayesh.jpg')
c.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=myimage)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is the directory name really `F  onts`??

Comment: Read about supported file formats [The Tkinter PhotoImage Class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: Yes sir it is F onts